Hindi vowel font issue after space
I am having issue with Hindi vowel font. When any Hindi vowel font like harsikar,drighikar, yekar and aukar with any Hindi font using after space, then it's misplaced with next font.
Here I am using to generate pdf from xslt. For font I am using Notosansdevanagari.ttf. please help me if you have any concern.
Here attached one screenshot for reference.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried using multiple hindi font like lohit,Mangal and sakalbharti also. But issue is same
